# Unknown HTTP GET request in React Native Application

Tags: reactjs, react-native, redux, realm, realm-js

Our tester captured some unknown GET request while doing API testing in our React Native application.

```
GET /inspector/device?name=some_unique_id&app=com.companyname.appname HTTP/1.1

Upgrade: websocket
Connection: Upgrade
Sec-WebSocket-Key: encrypted key
Sec-WebSocket-Version: 13
Host: localhost:8082
Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
User-Agent: okhttp/3.11.0
```

Could someone give me some idea what is this and why is this called.?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

It seems the line may comes from [**RCTInspectorDevServerHelper.mm**](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/master/React/DevSupport/RCTInspectorDevServerHelper.mm). You can see the line

```
return [NSURL URLWithString:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"http://%@/inspector/device?name=%@&app=%@",
                                                        getServerHost(bundleURL, inspectorProxyPort),
                                                        escapedDeviceName,
                                                        escapedAppName]];
```

inside **getInspectorDeviceUrl** function, which seems to be called each time the app is loaded to connect with the bundle.